Infinite series involving product of four gamma functions
I encountered the infinite series
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{1+n}{\Gamma\left(\frac12-n\right)\Gamma\left(\frac32-n\right)\left[\Gamma(2+n)\right]^2}$$
in my physics research and I know that it has to equal $16/(3\pi^2)$.
Mathematica can evaluate this sum but I can't because I don't have experience with infinite series that are this complicated. I would prefer to have a hand evaluation rather than relying on a computer algebra system.
How can I evaluate this infinite series by hand?

Here are 3 interesting properties of the Gamma function:

The well-known formula: $$\Gamma(z+1) = z\Gamma(z) \tag{1}$$
The reflection formula: for $z\notin \mathbb Z$,  $$\Gamma(z)\Gamma(1-z)=\frac \pi {\sin \pi z}\tag{2}$$
The Legendre reflection formula: $$\Gamma(z)\Gamma\left(z + \frac 1 2\right) = 2^{1-2z}\sqrt{\pi}\, \Gamma(2z) \tag{3}$$

Using $(1)$ with $z=\frac 1 2 - n$, we arrive at
$$\Gamma\left(\frac 3 2-n\right) = \left(\frac 1 2 -n \right)\Gamma\left(\frac 1 2-n\right)$$
Using $(2)$ with $z=\frac 1 2 -n$, we obtain
$$\Gamma\left(\frac 1 2-n\right) = \frac{(-1)^n\pi}{\Gamma\left(n+\frac 1 2\right)}$$
Using $(3)$ with $z=n$, we derive
$$\Gamma\left(n+ \frac 1 2\right) = 2^{1-2n}\sqrt{\pi}\,\frac{\Gamma(2n)}{\Gamma(n)}=4^{-n}\sqrt{\pi}\,\frac{(2n)!}{n!}$$
Chaining those last 3 results gives us:
$$\Gamma\left(\frac 1 2-n\right)\Gamma\left(\frac 3 2-n\right)= 16^{n}\pi\left(\frac 1 2 -n\right) \frac{(n!)^2}{((2n)!)^2}$$
Thus the series coefficients become $$\frac{1+n}{\Gamma\left(\frac12-n\right)\Gamma\left(\frac32-n\right)\left[\Gamma(2+n)\right]^2} =\frac 2 \pi\frac{1}{16^n } \frac{1}{n+1}\frac 1 {1-2n}\frac{((2n)!)^2}{(n!)^4}$$
Thus the series in question satisfies $$\begin{split}
S&=\frac 2 \pi \sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{1}{16^n } \frac{1}{n+1}\frac 1 {1-2n}\frac{((2n)!)^2}{(n!)^4} \\
&= \frac 2 \pi \sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{1}{16^n } \frac 1 {1-2n}\frac{((2n)!)^2}{(n!)^4} \int_0^1 x^n dx\\
&=\frac 2 \pi\int_0^1 \left ( \sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{1}{16^n } \frac 1 {1-2n}\frac{((2n)!)^2}{(n!)^4} x^n \right)dx\\
&= \frac 4 {\pi^2} \int_0^1 E(\sqrt x)dx
\end{split}$$
where we have identified the power series of the complete elliptic integral of the second kind.
Continuing with the integral form,
$$\begin{split}
S &= \frac 4 {\pi^2} \int_0^1 E(\sqrt x)dx\\
&= \frac 4 {\pi^2} \int_0^1 \int_0^1 \frac{\sqrt{1 - x t^2}}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}dt dx\\
&= \frac 4 {\pi^2} \int_0^1 \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-t^2}} \int_0^1 \sqrt{1 - x t^2}dx dt\\
&= -\frac {8} {3\pi^2} \int_0^1 \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}\cdot\frac{(1-t^2)^{\frac 3 2} - 1}{t^2}dt\\
&= -\frac {8} {3\pi^2} \left [ \frac{\sqrt{1-t^2}}{t}-\frac 1 t -t\right]_0^1
\end{split}$$
The bracket evaluates to $-2$, and we conclude:
$$\boxed{S=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{1+n}{\Gamma\left(\frac12-n\right)\Gamma\left(\frac32-n\right)\left[\Gamma(2+n)\right]^2}=\frac {16} {3\pi^2}}$$

Yikes, impressive!

Thank you very much :-)

@StefanLafon I'm trying to understand how people solve problems like this. I could follow you until "we have identified the power series of the complete elliptic integral of the second kind". If I had that expression, I probably would have just said it was hopeless mess and given up. How did you recognize it as as a known power series? Do you just have that in your head? Or did you get the suggestion from a computer algebra system?

Tables of power series are your friends :)
For instance https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series
I don't know those series by heart, but when I arrive at something that looks "reasonable", then I start fishing for it in one of those tables. If I'm lucky, like this this time around, I find my answer.

Consider $$f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(1+n)\,x^n}{\Gamma\left(\frac12-n\right)\Gamma\left(\frac32-n\right)\big[\Gamma(2+n)\big]^2}$$ Integrating
$$I(x)=\int f(x)\,dx=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{x^{n+1}}{\Gamma\left(\frac12-n\right)\Gamma\left(\frac32-n\right)\big[\Gamma(2+n)\big]^2}$$
Using the Gaussian hypergeometric function
$$I(x)=\frac {8}{3\pi}\left(\, _2F_1\left(-\frac{3}{2},-\frac{1}{2}
   ;1;x\right)-1\right)$$
Diferentiating
$$f(x)=I'(x)=\frac {2}{\pi}\,\,
   _2F_1\left(-\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2};2;x\right)$$
Using the relations between the Gaussian hypergeometric function and elliptic integrals
$$f(x)=I'(x)=\frac{8}{3 \pi ^2 x}\big((x-1)\, K(x)+(x+1)\, E(x) \big)$$ Therefore
$$f(1)=\frac{16 }{3 \pi ^2}E(1)=\frac{16 }{3 \pi ^2}$$
